# Android application bar

Tags: android, styles

Here is a pic of android applicationbar i like ( I mean the part where settings is written on, not sure if applicationbar is the right name :) )
http://oi50.tinypic.com/ehwwpc.jpg

Some apps i have downloaded also have the exact same bar so im guessing its a predefined theme but when i make a project (theme.holo) then my applicationbar  is just totally black.

So my question is how do i get the same project bar?

Thank you!

Edit:
I found that all apps are opensoruce and i looked out settings apps manifest for android 4.0.4, same as mine.

Here it is: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-4.0.4_r2.1/AndroidManifest.xml

Whats strange is that it uses the same theme i do: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"

... but still the titlebar is different. There must be another attribute somewhere that defines the titlebar? Does anyone have an idea? :)

Comment: It can be either an ActionBar or a TitleBar. Considering there's no actions on it, it looks like a TitleBar

Answer (score 0):

The title of the activity can be defined in the Manifest file, and it should be android:label property. For example:

```
<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/TitleBarText" />
```

TitleBarText is the android string resource that contains the name of the title.

If you wish to do it from code, you can just do the following in the onCreate method:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setTitle("Title Bar Name");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
```

To create a custom title bar, refer to: [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/) and [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar)

Comment: Sorry, but did you even read the question? :D
... i asked about the style of the titlebar, nothing about the title.
But still, thanks for anwsering :)

Comment: I feel like it's not very clear in your question. Maybe you should change the title to focus on the theme